# MCMC chain converges however log-posterior topology is incorrect for convergence

Tags: mcmc, stan

I used a Bayesian model in STAN to estimate a measurement error regression model. The diagnostics say the chain converged. However,  when I look at the parameter vs log-posterior plots. I find that the chain has not  explored the space where the log posterior is maximum. The figure shows the parameter vs log- posterior plot. We can see that the log posterior is still increasing to the right.
[image: Imgur]

I am trying to understand what could have caused this behavior, as the chains are converging to this unexpected point which is not a posterior mode for this marginal distribution. Why did HMC/NUTS not explore the space to the right where log-posterior is higher for this parameter?

The model I am fitting is:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;   // Sample size
  vector[N] X;      // Predictor
  vector[N] Y;      // Response
  real<lower=0> sigmax; // Measurement error in X
}
parameters {
  real beta0;       // intercept
  real beta1;       // X coefficient
  real<lower=0> sigma;  // error in Y
  vector[N] Xu;         // latent unmeasured X
}
model {
  X ~ normal(Xu,sigmax);
  Y ~ normal(beta0+beta1*Xu,sigma);  // likelihood
}
```

Comment: For a model such as this, it is entirely possible that the neighborhood of the mode has no probability. There are several explanations of this concentration of measure phenomenon in Stan models, such as this [case study](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/curse-dims.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the very nice case study. It says that "The rather surprising result is that for a normal distribution in high dimensions, the typical set does not include the volume around the mode". However, if I am understanding this correctly, HMC should sample on both sides of the mode, which doesn't look like what is happening in this example situation. Generally, even if the mode does not have enough probability it would sample around the mode and the estimates will not be biased when taking the average. I really appreciate any thoughts or tips to make HMC explore this space.

Comment: It can go on both (all) sides of the mode if there is both density and volume there. We refer to this as the donut. But sometimes the mode is on the edge and all the volume is to one side of it. I don't know for sure that is the case in your example, but it is an explanation for what you see in the plot.